# Mailbox app: Load images?

Tags: ios, applications

I am liking the app because it shows gmail conversations in a space efficient format, and its email search actually works.

Also the ability to keep lists of stuff *inside of my email* is pretty cool.

But it doesn't load images in emails. What's up with that?

Is there an option to enable it? Isn't this a basic feature?

Please don't say "performance reasons". The pictures should load asynchronously after all the text in the email loads.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work in the updated version I am running now.